# how have 6 recyclerview by same class and same cardview and 6 different arraylist?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm a self-learning.I have 3 recyclerview by 3 different arraylist but same cardview. How can I have one adapter class for this recylerviews ?
I write following code but it isn't true.

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

public static ArrayList <String> mainLinkImg1 = new ArrayList<>();//arraylists have valus
public static ArrayList <String> mainLinkImg2 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList <String> mainLinkImg3 = new ArrayList<>();

RecyclerView mainRecRow1,mainRecRow2,mainRecRow3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mainRecRow1 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainRec1);
    mainRecRow2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainRec2);
    mainRecRow3 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainRec3);

    mainRecRow1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    mainRecRow2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    mainRecRow3.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));


    AdapterRecMain adapterRecMainRow1 = new AdapterRecMain(this,mainLinkImg1);
    mainRecRow1.setAdapter(adapterRecMainRow1);
    adapterRecMainRow1.UpdateItem();

    AdapterRecMain adapterRecMainRow2 = new AdapterRecMain(this,mainLinkImg2);
    mainRecRow2.setAdapter(adapterRecMainRow2);
    adapterRecMainRow2.UpdateItem();

    AdapterRecMain adapterRecMainRow3 = new AdapterRecMain(this,mainLinkImg3);
    mainRecRow3.setAdapter(adapterRecMainRow3);
    adapterRecMainRow3.UpdateItem();

    }
}
```

and my adapter class...

```
public class AdapterRecMain extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> picLink;

public AdapterRecMain (Context con, ArrayList<String> imgLink){
    context= con;
    picLink.addAll(imgLink);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.main_cardview_item1,parent,false)
//main_cardview_item1 is my cardview layout and just has a imageview
    return new CellFeedViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final CellFeedViewHolder myHolder = (CellFeedViewHolder) holder;
    Picasso.with(context).load(picLink.get(position)).into(myHolder.mainImgRec);

}

public void UpdateItem()
{
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return picLink.size();
}

private class CellFeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView mainImgRec;
    CardView card;
    public CellFeedViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mainImgRec = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainCardViewImg);
        card = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainCardView1);
    }
}
}
```

Now what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I had mistake when I make Array list in my Adapter class

```
public static ArrayList <String> mainLinkImg1 = new ArrayList<>();
```